# rpm query does not give complete provided capabilities (commands)

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm

For example, I know /usr/sbin/agetty is provided by the `util-linux` package with the following command:

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/sbin/agetty
util-linux-2.24.1-1.fc20.x86_64
```

Then I would like to know what commands are provided by `util-linux`:

```
$ rpm -q --provides util-linux
/bin/dmesg
/bin/kill
/bin/more
/bin/mount
/bin/umount
/sbin/blkid
/sbin/blockdev
/sbin/findfs
/sbin/fsck
/sbin/nologin
config(util-linux) = 2.24.1-1.fc20
eject = 2.1.6
util-linux = 2.24.1-1.fc20
util-linux(x86-64) = 2.24.1-1.fc20
util-linux-ng = 2.24.1-1.fc20
```

As you can see, the output does not contain agetty. I was wondering if this is an exhaustive list. Any ideas how to get the complete list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I.e., you want to know which other files are in the package which contains `/usr/bin/agetty`:

```
rpm -qfl /usr/bin/agetty
```

Or if you want some provides that isn't a file:

```
rpm -ql --whatprovides MTA
```

You'll have to filter with `grep(1)` to get executables in standard places, i.e.,

```
rpm -qfl /usr/bin/agetty | grep '\(/usr/bin\|/bin\|/usr/sbin\|/sbin\)'
```

Comment: Thanks! It's the `--list, -l` option. So it is equivalent to use `rpm -ql --provides util-linux` to get the full list.